# Swift 2 open twitter app

Tags: twitter, swift2

since ios 9 and swift 2 this line of code

```
NSURL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=YOURNAME")
```

does not work anymore to open the twitter app, it will redirect to the website instead. 
I have been trying to fix this but cannot find anything. Somebody knows how to fix this?
Thank you for any help or support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually works again, definitely had problems for a few days where it would not open twitter app. Maybe signing out and back in settings-twitter did the trick.